# is it possible to create chatbot (using microsoft bot platform and luis) without azure platform

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

i want to create a bot service  without using azure platform. The bot application using microsoft bot platform and luis.

is there any solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a chat bot using Luis and Visual Studio followed by a Bot Emulator. You can create intents and entities in Luis and add them into the c# code as well.. But in order to publish the bot, you should have subscription in azure.

Answer (score 2):

No. In order to use the Bot Service or LUIS you need Azure (for both this is a requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Same conclusion - you have to create an account on Azure - Subscribe to it - Give your credit card and finally you can publish your bot (online).

It's weird to publish project on GitHub to finally make it freemium.
I hope Ms will make it possible in the framework V4.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have a MS Bot without an Azure subscription, because you have to register the bot with Azure, which doesn`t cost a dime. Speaking about costs the question is if you can use another hoster.

I have a botbuilder@4.0.0-preview1.2 that runs on DigitalOcean without problems. **Unfortunately the same is at the moment not the case with release @4.1.2 though. I tend to say no solution for the official release although it works in the emulator.**

Trying to make the underneath changes with botbuilder@4.1.7 results in: "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ServiceUnavailable"

In order to make "botbuilder@4.0.0-preview1.2" work I made following changes to the index.ts and bot.ts coming from this example https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_typescript/13.basic-bot/src/index.ts .

1) Delete this import (index.ts)

```
// import { BotConfiguration, IEndpointService } from 'botframework-config';
```

2) Delete this configuration (index.ts)

```
// const BOT_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '..', (process.env.botFilePath || ''));
// let botConfig: BotConfiguration;
// try {
//     // Read bot configuration from .bot file.
//     botConfig = BotConfiguration.loadSync(BOT_FILE, process.env.botFileSecret);
// } catch (err) {
//     console.error(`\nError reading bot file. Please ensure you have valid botFilePath and botFileSecret set for your environment.`);
//     console.error(`\n - The botFileSecret is available under appsettings for your Azure Bot Service bot.`);
//     console.error(`\n - If you are running this bot locally, consider adding a .env file with botFilePath and botFileSecret.`);
//     console.error(`\n - See https://aka.ms/about-bot-file to learn more about .bot     file its use and bot configuration.\n\n`);
//     process.exit();
// }
```

3) get rid of this (index.ts)

```
// const BOT_CONFIGURATION = (process.env.NODE_ENV || DEV_ENVIRONMENT);
// const endpointConfig = <IEndpointService>botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(BOT_CONFIGURATION);
```

4) REPLACE (index.ts)

```
// const adapter : BotFrameworkAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
//     appId: endpointConfig.appId || process.env.microsoftAppID,
//     appPassword: endpointConfig.appPassword || process.env.microsoftAppPassword
// });
```

WITH

```
const adapter : BotFrameworkAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.microsoftAppID,
    appPassword: process.env.microsoftAppPassword
});
```

5) REPLACE  (index.ts)

```
// let bot: BasicBot;
// try {
//     bot = new BasicBot(conversationState, userState, botConfig);
// } catch (err) {
//     console.error(`[botInitializationError]: ${ err }`);
//     process.exit();
// }
```

WITH

```
let bot: BasicBot;
try {
    bot = new BasicBot(conversationState, userState);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`[botInitializationError]: ${ err }`);
    // process.exit();
}
```

6) Now in bot.ts change the signature of the Bot-constructor by deleting the 3rd param  "botConfig"https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_typescript/13.basic-bot/src/bot.ts.

REPLACE

```
// constructor(conversationState: ConversationState, userState: UserState, botConfig: BotConfiguration) {...
```

WITH

```
constructor(conversationState: ConversationState, userState: UserState) {...
```

7) Delete all references to botConfig in bot.ts, since this seems only to be used for additional Azure Services

```
// if (!botConfig) throw ('Missing parameter.  botConfig is required');
//
// add the LUIS recognizer
// let luisConfig: LuisService;
// luisConfig = <LuisService>botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(LUIS_CONFIGURATION);
// if (!luisConfig || !luisConfig.appId) throw ('Missing LUIS configuration. Please follow README.MD to create required LUIS applications.\n\n');
// this.luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
//     applicationId: luisConfig.appId,
//
// CAUTION: Its better to assign and use a subscription key instead of authoring key here.
//     endpointKey: luisConfig.authoringKey,
//     endpoint: luisConfig.getEndpoint()
// });
```

8) Don`t forget to delete all logic based on the deleted variables of step 7 in the bot.ts.